# Connecting Multiple Docker Apps

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container

I run a series of sites that run independently but need to be able to make curl calls via PHP to a custom single sign on service.

If I set all the sites up as separate container stacks (meaning that sso has it's own set of shared containers (Nginx, PHP, and MySQL) and site1 has its own set of shared containers and the same with site2, site3, and site4) then they can't talk to each other. I've tried setting up a custom network, but then I have to include a host file that specifies the IP address of the SSO server URL so that the other sites can connect to it.

This is my current docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.10.3
    ports:
        - "8080:80"
        - "8443:443"
    volumes:
        - ./projects:/var/www
        - ./.docker/nginx/sites-enabled/site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
        - ./.docker/nginx/sites-enabled/site-ssl.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site-ssl.conf
        - ./.docker/certs:/etc/nginx/certs
    links:
        - php
    networks:
      mc-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.245.0.2
  php:
    build:
        context: ./.docker/fpm
    volumes:
        - ./projects:/var/www
        - ./.docker/sessions.inc.php:/var/www/sessions/sessions.inc.php
        - ./.docker/fpm/hosts.txt:/etc/hosts
    expose:
        - "9000"
    links:
      - percona:percona
    networks:
      mc-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.245.0.3
  percona:
    image: percona/percona-server:5.6
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: *****
      TZ: America/Los_Angeles
    ports:
        - "8306:3306"
    volumes:
        - ./.docker/database:/var/lib/mysql
    command:
        - 'sh -c "ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles /etc/localtime && echo America/Los_Angeles > /etc/timezone"'
        - '--user=mysql'
    networks:
      mc-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.245.0.4
networks:
  mc-net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.245.0.0/16
```

I'm a novice at Docker and I just need a way to make it so site1 can curl to sso via its URL. I'm not sure where to go with this, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a docker network for all the containers and just make your calls to the sso container by its name. You don't even need to expose the port for your sso if all the services using it are inside the docker network.

`ssodockername:port`